# PublicKey issues when deploying the project

Tags: c#, packaging, public-key

I have the following problem when deploying the project:

> Warning 8 The value of the 'PublicKey' attribute in 'Microsoft Report
> Viewer 2012 Runtime' does not match that of file 'C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft
> SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\ReportViewer\ReportViewer.msi'.

It is the same for the other components:

> Warning 6 The value of the 'PublicKey' attribute in 'Microsoft® System
> CLR Types for SQL Server® 2012 (x86)' does not match that of file
> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlClrTypes_x86\SQLSysClrTypes.msi'.

This warning can not be ignored since it creates problem when installing the software on the other device.

Comment: have you looked in GAC for the correct key?

Comment: I have downloaded the packages as it was advised. Also, I have unblocked the packages so it can be read. But still it has the same problem. What do you mean by GAC checking.

Comment: view that assembly version,publickey,in the GAC,then check in your assembly if they dont match.C:\Windows\assembly

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I check the GAC value?

Comment: when inside that folder look for that assembly name then right-click it and properties to check publickey

Comment: I tried to locate those component in the folder C:\Windows\assembly which has the assemblies but I failed. Can you please give hint

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32600/discussion-between-terrybozzio-and-user2103335)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio checks a file called `Product.xml` for details about installer prerequisites. This file will be in the same location as the installer cited in the warning.

For each warning you need to update the `PackageFile` property `PublicKey` to match the installer you are using. As new versions come out, the signature might change but the `Product.xml` is not included with new installer version and thus it doesn't always match.

To resolve this issue:

Update the Package Data

- Open the `[Program Files]\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\$Version\Bootstrapper\Packages\$PackageName folder`
- Right-Click the installer package cited.
- Select Properties
- Select `Digital Signatures` tab
- Select `sha1` digest from the signature list
- Click `Details`
- Click `View Certificate`
- Select `Details` tab
- Select `Public Key`
- Copy all the text from the preview window
- Paste it in to a text editor
- Use Find\Replace tool to remove all spaces from the key
- Edit the `Product.xml` file.
- Find the element for `<PackageFile Name="$PackageName"` and change the `PublicKey`
- Save the `Product.xml` file.
- Repeat for each package with this warning.