# Why does the value of the PublicKey attribute of .NET Framework not match in ClickOnce?

Tags: .net, winforms, clickonce

I downloaded and extracted the .NET framework 3.5 bootstrapper files.

There are no errors while publishing, but I get the following two warnings:

> The value of the 'PublicKey' attribute in '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1'
>   does not match that of file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio
>   14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFX30\XPSEPSC-amd64-en-US.exe'.

and

> The value of the 'PublicKey' attribute in '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1'
>   does not match that of file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio
>   14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFX30\XPSEPSC-x86-en-US.exe'.

What can I do to address these warnings?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221913/net-3-5-sp1-bootstrapper-not-found-for-setup

Comment: @OfirW Thanks, it solved the problem. As the question is different, do you want to enter the same as an answer here? Or shall we mark it as a duplicate?

Comment: Duplicate i think

Comment: The accepted answer on that question is a link only answer. This should not have been closed as duplicate. It deserves a proper explanation.

Comment: I give a detailed answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374809/publickey-issues-when-deploying-the-project/64992268#64992268